# Problem with \part (Numbering, partend,

Tags: sectioning, numbering, parts

my code is like this:

```
\input{sections/Preface}\clearpage
\part{Problems}
\input{sections/Text1}\clearpage
\input{sections/Text2}\clearpage
\part{solutions}
\input{sections/sol1}\clearpage
\input{sections/sol2}\clearpage
\input{sections/sol3}\clearpage
\input{sections/sol4}\clearpage
\input{sections/Closingword}\clearpage
```

The things I would like to change:

- Remove Numbering from Preface (Using section* in the file makes it disappear from the table of contents)
- Restart Numbering whenever a new part starts (So Sol1 is numbered as #1 and not #3)
- Remove numbering from the closingword and make it not included in the second part
- On the PDF itself, Problems is written twice and I only want it one time there (Twice makes no sense to me and I don't know how to change it)

P.S. I'm not allowed to use any other documentclass as I'm given

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use \section* and you want it to appear to the table of contents, you can use the \addcontentsline command. Something like this:

```
\section*{Section 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Section 1}%
```

To restart the numbering of any part/section, you can use the set counter command:

```
\setcounter{section}{0}
```

It will reset the counter to 0, so when you start again, it will be 1.

Comment: Thanks, that solved everything!
Also the partnaming displaying twice got fixed by that too!
Just had to change it to part* to only display the text once. The problem here was that it disappeared from the TOC too. But with your line \addcontentsline I got it to be included by changing section to part.
Thank you for your quick answer!